# Maintain existing indentation with `!` command in Vim

Tags: vim, editor, indentation

I'm trying to clean up a bunch of yaml files in vim. The yaml files are fixtures for tests, and they contain literal strings of XML. They look like:

```
-
  - "<xml>blah blah blah …1000 characters later</xml>"
  - "<more>…</more>"
```

I want them to look like:

```
-
  - >
    <xml>
      <nicely>formatted</nicely>
      …
    </xml>
  - >
    <more>
      …
    </more>
```

I strip the quotes, put the cursor at the beginning of the unformatted xml and hit `>`, enter, `<tab>`, I get

```
-
  - >
    <xml>…
```

But then I try to format the xml the only way I know how: `shift`-`v` to select the line. `:'<,'>!xmllint --nocdata --format - | awk 'NR>1'` to format the xml, and I get

```
-
  - >
<xml>
  <nicely>formatted</nicely>
  …
</xml>
```

and then I have to reselect the xml and use `2>>` to reindent.

Is there a better way to maintain the indentation when executing a `!` command in Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't state this outright, but it somewhat implies that vim is the reason the indentation is stripped, so just to be clear, the indentation is being taken out by xmllint.

You could try to save the indentation first, but that could be confusing if the indentation is different amongst the different lines.  In this case it probably makes more sense from looking at the commands you are running to just add the indentation later - you can do it automatically by adding it to your command filter, such as:

`:'<,'>!xmllint --nocdata --format - | awk 'NR>1' | sed -e 's/^/\t/'`